# showing type error while building the next js project

Tags: typescript, typeerror, next.js13

[this is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGrVy.png)
[here is the build code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWbNL.png)

[here is the development code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kilHz.png)

[here is the inventory type code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFJ36.png)
It is showing type error after building my next js project.

I am expecting to remove this type error. because in the development mode there is no such of type error

Answer (score 0):

firstly Replace :
**import as entry from**
with
**import entry from**
and 2ndly change this
**function checkFields<T extends Diff<TEntry, TEntry>>(**